# R Shiny Wrapping a very long string in main panel

Tags: r, shiny

I have very long string and I am trying to wrap this inside the main panel of R Shiny.

This is what I have in ui.R under main panel. The 'contents' variable contains the long string. (1000+) characters. Currently, the string extends out of the page and I have to scroll horizontally to view the whole string. I would like for this sting to wrap around like in a text box within the main panel.

```
mainPanel(
  textOutput('contents')
)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer

I used `verbatimTextOutput` instead of `textOutput` and this did exactly what I wanted.